# music is not playing smoothly when updating seekbar every 1 second

Tags: java, android, android-studio, timer

After adding Timer() method seekbar should be updated every second, it is getting updated but their is a small pause like updating seekbar require a time to update... this has cause seekbar is not running smoothly gives a feel that there is a lag...

```
package com.example.musicplayer;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    AudioManager audioManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.senorita);
        audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        int myMaxValume= audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        int myCurrentValume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        SeekBar valumeRocker = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        valumeRocker.setMax(myMaxValume);
        valumeRocker.setProgress(myCurrentValume);

        valumeRocker.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,progress,0);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
        //timeline part of music app
        final SeekBar timeline = findViewById(R.id.timeline);

        timeline.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());

        //set onChange listner on timeline
        timeline.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
        //customise timeline seekbar

        new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                                timeline.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                                            }
                                        }
                , 0, 1000);
    }
    public void playMe(View view){
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
    public void pauseMe(View view){
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }
}
```

if i remover Timer method.. every this is fine ... i guess i have done something woring in this ...

help me out

thank you in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check 'fromUser' variable is true or not on seekbar progress changed. Because you will get seekbar change callback in both cases, when the user change manually and when Timer update seekbar progress.

Updated code:-

```
package com.example.musicplayer;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
AudioManager audioManager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.senorita);
    audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int myMaxValume= audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    int myCurrentValume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    SeekBar valumeRocker = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    valumeRocker.setMax(myMaxValume);
    valumeRocker.setProgress(myCurrentValume);

    valumeRocker.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,progress,0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
    //timeline part of music app
    final SeekBar timeline = findViewById(R.id.timeline);

    timeline.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());

    //set onChange listner on timeline
    timeline.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if (fromUser) mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
    //customise timeline seekbar

    new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            timeline.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                                        }
                                    }
            , 0, 1000);
}
public void playMe(View view){
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
public void pauseMe(View view){
    mediaPlayer.pause();
}
}
```